# Launching desired version of XCode from Finder

Tags: xcode, ide, macos

My google-fu has failed me, and I guess this may be basic OS X/Xcode knowledge but....

When I double click .xcodeproj files, I'm getting the Beta I have installed launching instead of the stable release - which is the one I actually want.

I have tried changing the launch program in the finder info window, but it always displays as "Xcode" and doesn't seem to accept that there are different versions - even though it offers them to me in the drop down list.

Is there an xcode setting for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed in two different locations?

Comment: Yes, The stable version (3.2.1) is in /Developer, and the Beta is in /DeveloperBeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line tool `xcode-select` is what you want:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

You will have to use `sudo` to actually change it with `-switch`.